# How to find element position while scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

On a webpage, in iPhone, I want to be able to know what the scrollLeft value is of a scrolling div after it is swiped and while it is still moving. It seems like Chrome and Safari simply don't update this value regularly. I've also tried to grab $.position().left of the first item in the scrolling div and $.offset().left as well instead of the div's scrollLeft value, and likewise they are not updated regularly. They seem to return the same value over and over while the div is in motion, and then finally update when it stops or comes close to stopping. I want to know the left position of the content of the div, or the scrollLeft position of the div itself, every 10 ms or so while it is in motion. But the data just never changes!

I've tried monitoring via onScroll, which is not fired anywhere near often enough, and I've also tried monitoring using setInterval. setInterval goes off when I want it to, but like I said, the left position data is not frequently updated as expected.

jQuery or vanilla JS can both be used in any answer.

Any suggestions would be very helpful, especially if they have the necessary code!

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have the time to write out a full example, but have you tried testing `.getBoundingClientRect()`?

Comment: That is a problem with the Apple products. The scroll will never change or trigger while the inertia is not stopped. The solution is to use a custom scroll plugin like [iScroll](http://lab.cubiq.org/iscroll5/demos/simple/) where you'll be able to detect scroll event and position.

Comment: Conexion, I tried getBoundingClientRect and had the exact same problem.